# Finding a sequence in a line of letters

Tags: python

I work with mRNA and would like to identify particular letter sequences in a line of mRNA. mRNA is a string of letters that codes for proteins (It can be represented as .txt or .fasta file). The mRNA string consists of letters "A","U","G" and "C" and can be tens of thousands of letters long. mRNA can also be methylated at Adenine ("*A*") particular sequences in the cell. In humans, methylation occurs at sequence "**DR***A*C**H**", where "**D**" can represent letters A/G/U, "**R**"=A/G and "**H**"=U/A/C, which would give a total of 3x2x3=18 potential letter combinations if my math is right. I want to write a code in Python that would read my .txt/.fasta file with the mRNA string, scan it for all 18 "DRACH" sequences, list them and highlight them in the sequence.

I created a mock .txt file (C:\rna\RNA_met.txt) containing the string: "AACGAUUCGACCGCA**AGACU**GGGC**GAACC**AUUCUAA"

It has 2 DRACH sequences: AGACU and GAACC.

I haven't done any coding but I suspect that my task can be broken down into subtasks. Subtask 1 would be to make a program 'read' my .txt file. The second task would be to teach the program to recognise the DRACH sequence. The 3rd task would be to make python to show the mRNA string with highlighted DRACH sequences.

for subtask 1, I printed the following code in Spyder:

```
file = open('RNA_met.txt', 'r')
f = file.readlines()
print(f)
```

There were no mistakes in the code. Unfortunately, I did not see my sequence.
I tried to change to the whole file pathway as:

```
f = open("C:\\rna\RNA_met.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

but it also didn't help.

Any ideas on how may I fix the first subtask before moving onto the second one?

Thanks!
Maria

Comment: Your code does look like it *should* work. A few checks: What does the code output (if anything)? Is the .txt file in the same folder as the .py file  (i.e. does the code find the file in the right folder - one way to check this is to use the complete path - which you've done but watch those \\ and \)?

Comment: did you check file-rights? maybe its not the same as executable

Comment: This sounds like a simple regex problem. The pattern `[AGU][AG]AC[UAC]` will match your DRACH strings. Just run `re.findall` with that pattern on your data. I'm not sure I understand what is the problem with your code in the question. Don't you see the contents of the file printed? What do you mean *"I did not see my sequence"*?

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of Python dictionaries *(hash tables)* to come up with an efficient solution like the following:

```
f = open("RNA_met.txt", "r")
seq = f.read()

#In this case, the content of .txt was "AACGAUUCGACCGCAAGACUGGGCGAACCAUUCUAA"
combinations = {}
for i in ["A", "G", "U"]:
  for j in ["A", "G"]:
    for k in ["U", "A", "C"]:
      combinations[f"{i}{j}AC{k}"] = ""

for i in range(0, len(seq)-5):
    if seq[i:i+5] in combinations:
        print(seq[i:i+5], "Sequence found on: ", i)
```

**Output:**

```
AGACU Sequence found on:  15
GAACC Sequence found on:  24
```

This algorithm storages all possible combinations of `"DRACH"` sequences into a hash table and traverses the `.txt` file to find potential matches. When found, it prints the match and its position into the file with the long sequence of letters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is full solution using regex (very useful to work with string)

```
import re
from typing import Dict, List

D = "[AGU]"
R = "[AG]"
A = "A"
C = "C"
H = "[UAC]"

RE_DRACH_PATTERN = re.compile(f"{D}{R}{A}{C}{H}")


def find_drach_seq(mrna_seq: str) -> List[Dict]:
    ret = []
    for a_match in re.finditer(RE_DRACH_PATTERN, mrna_seq):
        ret.append(
            {"start": a_match.start(), "end": a_match.end(), "drach": a_match.group()}
        )
    return ret


def find_drach_in_file(in_file_path: str) -> List[Dict]:
    ret = []
    current_line = 0
    with open(in_file_path, "r", encoding="UTF-8") as fr:
        for line in fr:
            current_line += 1
            drach_matches = find_drach_seq(line)
            for a_match in drach_matches:
                a_match["line"] = current_line
                ret.append(a_match)
    return ret


if __name__ == "__main__":
    mrna_seq = "AACGAUUCGACCGCAAGACUGGGCGAACCAUUCUAA"
    for a_match in find_drach_seq(mrna_seq):
        print(a_match)
    in_file = "m_rna.txt"
    for a_match in find_drach_in_file(in_file_path=in_file):
        print(a_match)
```

My wife is a pathology doctor and at some point may need to learn about mRNA (I forgot the name of specialization). It would be great if we could share.

Anyway, your second code missing an escape: `C:\\rna\\RNA_met.txt`

Comment: Dear colleagues, thank you very much for sharing the suggestions. I will use them to edit my code accordingly. @TrungLe, please share this paper with your wife, it describes the methylation of mRNA in humans: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/acs.biochem.1c00254